# Problem with behavior of DIV FLEX on iPad

Tags: css

I keep facing a strange problem on my website when it is displayed on an iPad (phone, etc works fine, also no problems on devtool responsive mode ).

[Here is the problem on my live site](http://mardeipoeti.com/#sicily)

I have 3 images displayed inside a flex div, the height of the div is not set and it adapts depending on the width of the images ( 32 % ). It's okay on any device, but on iPad it get stretched. I'm having trouble finding where the problem is. ( BTW how do you debug on iPad ? )

```css
.sicily_pics {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: fit-content;
}

.sicily_pics img {
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: auto;
}

.sicily_pics img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sicily_pics">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/375x500" alt="Greek Theater in Taormina">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/375x500" alt="Isola Bella">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/375x500" alt="Mount Etna">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In most contexts, `align-items` defaults to `stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#values) on flex containers such as `.sicily_pics`. To change this, you need to add something like `align-items: start`, `align-items: end`, or `align-items: baseline` to the element. This will prevent the images from being stretched to the height of the tallest image.

```css
.sicily_pics {
  /* ... */
  align-items: start;
}
```

This change will give you images of different heights, however, which you may not want. If you want to keep the images in line with each other and resize them by *cropping*, rather than *stretching*, you can leave the flex container alone and instead add `object-fit: cover` to the images.

```css
.sicily_pics img {
  /* ... */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**Side note:** You can remove the `height: auto` from the images – `auto` is the default value for `<img>` elements.

**Side note 2:** You need Safari on macOS to debug Safari on iOS or iPadOS:

[image: Screenshot of debugging in Safari developer tools]